# Extra param for logging

Tags: python, logging, yaml, config

I want to pass extra logging param in Uvicorn server at FastAPI application.
Now im using

```
extra = {"source": "any source"}
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
```

But I need to configure logger with yaml file
I got file like this

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

filters:
  masking:
    (): core.logging_.filters.maskingfilter.MaskingFilter
    mask: "*****"

handlers:
  socket:
    (): core.logging_.handlers.jsonsockethandler.JSONSocketHandler
    filters:
      - masking
    host: '0.0.0.0'
    port: 9021

root:
  handlers:
    - socket
  level: DEBUG
```

So my question is how can to put extra param with source to yaml config?

Comment: But in production, is the actual stuff in `extra` a fixed value like in your example? I assume not - but if it's dynamic (e.g. remote IP) why would that be in the config?

Comment: @VinaySajip yeah it's fixed value. it's the name of the project that sends log to my special log receiver.